# Try to pass variable information from a listview to a new activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I am new to Android application programming and I have been struggling for several days now to pass information from an item in a listview on a click. I am posting what I have done to this point here.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LeagueAdapter mLeagueAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLeagueAdapter = new LeagueAdapter();

        final ListView listLeague = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listLeague.setAdapter(mLeagueAdapter);


        // Handle clicks on the ListView
        listLeague.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int whichItem, long id) {

                /*
                    Create  a temporary League
                    Which is a reference to the League
                    that has just been clicked
                */
                // Create a new dialog window
                //DialogShowLeague dialog = new DialogShowLeague();

                // Send in a reference to the League to be shown
                //dialog.sendLeagueSelected(tempLeague);

                // Show the dialog window with the League in it
                //dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");


                String selected = ListView[whichItem];
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlersActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("name", selected);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createNewLeague(League n){

        mLeagueAdapter.addLeague(n);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_addLeague) {
            DialogNewLeague dialog = new DialogNewLeague();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class LeagueAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        List<League> leagueList = new ArrayList<League>();

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return leagueList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public League getItem(int whichItem) {
            // Returns the requested league
            return leagueList.get(whichItem);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int whichItem) {
            // Method used internally
            return whichItem;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(
                int whichItem, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            /*
                Prepare a list item to show our data
                The list item is contained in the view parameter
                The position of the data in our ArrayList is contained
                in whichItem parameter
            */


            // Has view been inflated already
            if(view == null){

                // No. So do so here
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_league_list_item, viewGroup,false);

            }// End if

            // Grab a reference to all our TextView and ImageView widgets
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            // Hide any ImageView widgets that are not relevant
            League tempLeague = leagueList.get(whichItem);

            // Add the text to the heading and description
            txtTitle.setText(tempLeague.getTitle());

            return view;
        }

        public void addLeague(League n){

            leagueList.add(n);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }

}
```

DialogNewLeague.java

```
public class DialogNewLeague extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_league, null);

        final EditText editTitle = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelLeague);
        Button btnOK = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddLeague);

        builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Add New mLeague");

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Handle the OK button
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Create a new note
                League newLeague = new League();

                // Set its variables to match the users entries on the form
                newLeague.setTitle(editTitle.getText().toString());

                // Get a reference to MainActivity
                MainActivity callingActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

                // Pass newNote back to MainActivity
                callingActivity.createNewLeague(newLeague);

                // Quit the dialog
                dismiss();
            }
        });


        return builder.create();

    }

}
```

League.java

```
package rvogl.ca.mydialog;

public class League {

    private String mLeague;

    public String getTitle() {
        return mLeague;
    }

    public void setTitle(String mLeague) {
        this.mLeague = mLeague;
    }
}
```

BowlersActivty.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BowlersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    League mLeague;
    String title;
    String editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bowlers);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = extras.getString("name");
        editText.setText(name);

    }
}
```

I have been through almost all the posts on this site that I can find and I have tried several of them without any success.

At this point now the app just crashes when I click on an item in the league listview.

Any suggests and advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

I am able to get the information to an Alert Dialog using the following:

DialogShowLeague

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DialogShowLeague extends DialogFragment {

        League mLeague;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_show_league, null);

            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtTitle.setText(mLeague.getTitle());


            Button btnOK = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

            builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Your mLeague");

            btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });



        return builder.create();
    }


    public void sendLeagueSelected(League leagueSelected) {
        mLeague = leagueSelected;
    }

}
```

Is it not possible to accomplish this using something similar.  I just don't know what to replace dialogView with.

Comment: through an intent you can pass data, if its a custom class's object try using serizable/parcelable

Comment: What do you mean by crashes ? What's the error message ?

Comment: At the moment I know I have a problem in with the following:

app/src/main/java
        rvogl/ca/mydialog/MainActivity.java
        error: cannot find symbol variable ListView
        rvogl/ca/mydialog/BowlersActivity.java
        error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)


This is because I have been messing around with different code samples from different post that I have been reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out using the following code:

MainActivity

```
mLeagueAdapter = new LeagueAdapter();

        final ListView listLeague = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listLeague.setAdapter(mLeagueAdapter);
        listLeague.setOnItemClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) {

                String leagueName = mLeagueAdapter.getItem(pos).getTitle();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BowlersActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("value1", leagueName);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

In my second Activity BowlersActivity.java

```
    String savedExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("value1");
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueName);
    myText.setText(savedExtra);
```

My problem was that I was attempting to get the league name from an empty variable "selected"  Once I got the position of the League that I was clicking on in the list view by using the my mLeagueAdapter, passing it on by .putExtra was no longer an issue.

@Fazal Hussain thank-you so much for all your patience and assistance it was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value on listview click like the code below. Implement Serializable interface in your model class i.e League

```
listLeague.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 

    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id) { 
         League selected = (League)adaper.getItemAtPosition(pos);

         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlersActivity.class); 
         i.putExtra("name", (Serializable)selected);             
         startActivity(i); 
    }
 });
```

**Edit**

Replace your model class with this

```
public class League implement Serializable { 
    private String mLeague; 

    public String getTitle() { 
        return mLeague; 
    } 

    public void setTitle(String mLeague) {
        this.mLeague = mLeague;
    } 
}
```

Get data on second activity like this

```
String name = extras.getSerializableExtra("name").getTitle();
```

Comment: I tried placing your code into my League class and I am getting unresolved method for getApplicationContext().  unresolved symbols for i.putExtra as well as an unresolved symbol for Serializeable and selected.

I am not sure why I would be passing the data with intent in the League class when I already have a onclicklistener in the MainActivity which is passing the the intent to the new activity BowlersActivity.  Can you explain this?

Comment: I put the code above in my MainActivity and tried recalling it from my BowlersActivity class with the following into my BowlersActivity   
Intent intent = getIntent();  
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);  
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueName);  
        textView.setText(text);  
When I click on an item in the listview it goes to the second activity but does not display the information from the list item that was click on.  Also when I go back to the first activity the list information is gone.

Comment: How do I resolve symbol extras,  I have tried resolving it with Bundle which worked but then .getSerializable('name") cannot be resolved. Not sure what I am doing wrong at this point.

Comment: Use getIntent.getSerializableExtra("name");

Comment: Unfortunately String name = getIntent.getSerializableExtra("name")...  gives me the same result, getIntent is an unresolveable symbol. Is getIntent a string that needs to be declared?  If I declare it .getSerializableExtra becomes unresolved

Comment: I have added my DialogShowLeague above.  I am able to successfully show the information to an Alert Dialog,  is it not possible use something similar to show the information in a new Activity?

Comment: I am now getting the following error : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: My code looks like the following : public class BowlersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    League mLeague;
    private String name;
    public Intent getIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bowlers);

        getIntent.getSerializableExtra("name");
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueName);
        textView.setText(name);


    }
}

Comment: By the way is there a way to enter in new code segments so they are formatted correctly rather than having it all bunched up like in my comment above?

Comment: Check the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android&ved=2ahUKEwjt-Y_7qPHaAhUJG5oKHc95DRMQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0-NQ9d-tH6A1N9rmsTBcew